# Parse: Dynamic datas in push notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parse-platform

Notification Using Parse from Server.
I have to send different message for a set of users

like,

```
you got 1st rank   - to User A
you got 2nd rank   - to User B
you got 3rd rank   - to User C
```

In Parse, i have save the rank details for each users like

```
device_id  userA    rank1
device_id  userB    rank2
device_id  userc    rank3
```

While pushing the message, i have the send the message with the rank value

```
url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push'
message = 'you got Xth rank'
data = {:data => message}.to_json
HTTParty.post(url,:body => data)
```

I can able to send the static message with the above code.
But how to send the message with dynamic values from parse database of respective record.

Answer (score 1):

Looping through users and sending them push one by one may be the solution to your problem, Here is an example code in JS

```js
var installationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
installationQuery.each(
  function(result) {
  var tempQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  tempQuery.equalTo("username", result.get('username'));
  // Send push notification to query
  Parse.Push.send({
    where: tempQuery,
    //
    data: {
   alert: "Hey "+result.get('name')+" your Rank ."+ result.get('rank')
    }
  }, {
    success: function() {
   response.success("Pushed to "+result.get('name'));
    },
    error: function(error) {
   // Handle error
   response.success("Error in push to"+result.get('name'));
    }
  });
   
  }, 
  {
  success: function(result) {
  console.log("push sent to all users.");
  response.success();
  },
  error: function() {
  
  
  } }
  );
```

And if your data for ranks isn't in installation e.g. it's in Users Table then your first query would be on Users table and in function on each to send push you second query will remain on installation table.
Any query?